# How to get a specific resource with a GET request using python3?

Tags: python, rest, get

Hello I am trying to solve this problem currently. How would one go about getting a specific resource, i.e. "resources/2021/helloworld" from a web service at a specific url (example.com/example) using python? I also need to specify a user agent (chrome on android in this case) and a link which it was referred by (i.e. google.com/resourcelink). Then preferrably print the text of the resource or write it to a file.

Comment: What web framework are you using?

Comment: Simply trying to use the requests library in python. I'm open to using a framework to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whatever you want to achieve can be simple done using request lib with minimal effort.

Comment: There are tons and tons of examples how to use the requests library, how to do get requests with it, how to set the user agent and other headers. Read some of them, and come back with code you (!) wrote, and a real question (i.e. a question that does not read *"I need someone to write this for me..."*)